# Add function to ZSH

Tags: zsh

With the default terminal, after I added the following function to my `.bash_profile` file I was able to call it with `docker-clean` in the terminal.

```
function docker-clean() {
  docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
  docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
  docker rmi $(docker images -q)
  docker volume prune
}
```

I've now switched to ZSH and adding the same thing to my `.zshrc` doesnt work, the command is not found.

Comment: That should work. There is insufficient information in your question to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: What other information can I provide?

Comment: I'm not a zsh user, so I've no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), try making your function a custom plugin. Put the code in a new file saved to this directory `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins`.

> If you have many functions that go well together, you can put them as
>   a XYZ.plugin.zsh file in the custom/plugins/ directory and then enable
>   this plugin. [GitHub](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#custom-plugins-and-themes)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here may have been that you need to run the following for the functions to be usable.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker-clean() {
  docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
  docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
  docker rmi $(docker images -q)
  docker volume prune
}
```

Try dropping the function keyword...